# Linking empty TD - HTML Email

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-table, html-email

I have a html email template that I am trying to set up for a client. The issue I am having is that I need to have 4 colour blocks that are empty and can not include images. These need to link through to an external site, I can create the tds to be empty colour blocks but I cannot make them fully clickable. Does anyone have any ideas?  Code below.

```html
<div style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; overflow:hidden;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px 5px; margin: 0 0; width: 320px;">
        <tr>
            <td width="25%" style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center;">
                <a style=" text-decoration: none !important; padding: 30px 10px; width: 106px; background: #cd3333; color: #cd3333; display: block;" class="red" width="106px" height="65px" href="http://www.google.co.uk">                    
                   <table style="background: #cd3333; color: #cd3333;">
                       <tr>
                            <td width="106" height="65"><a href=" href="http://www.google.co.uk" style="padding: 30px 10px; color:#CC3333; text-decoration: none !important;">Unhappy</a></td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>                    
                </a>
            </td>
            
            <td width="25%" style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center;">
                <a style=" text-decoration: none !important; padding: 30px 10px; width: 106px; background: #ffb50e; color: #ffb50e; display: block;" href=" href="http://www.google.co.uk" class="amber" width="106px" height="65px">                    
                    <table style="background: #ffb50e; color: #ffb50e;">
                       <tr>
                            <td width="106" height="65"><a href=" href="http://www.google.co.uk" style="padding: 30px 10px; color:#FFB40D; text-decoration: none !important;">Acceptable</a></td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>                    
                </a>
            </td>
            
            <td width="25%" style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center;">
                <a style=" text-decoration: none !important; padding: 30px 10px; width: 106px; background: #67cb33; color: #67cb33; display: block;"  class="green" width="106px" height="65px" href=" href="http://www.google.co.uk">                    
                    <table style="background: #67cb33; color: #67cb33;">
                       <tr>
                            <td width="106" height="65"><a href=" href="http://www.google.co.uk" style="padding: 30px 10px; color:#66CC33; text-decoration: none !important;">Happy</a></td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>                    
                </a>
            </td>
    
            <td width="25%" style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center;">
                <a style=" text-decoration: none !important; padding: 30px 10px; width: 106px; background: #b9850d; color: #b9850d; display: block;"  class="gold" width="106px" height="65px" href=" href="http://www.google.co.uk">                    
                    <table style="background: #b9850d; color: #b9850d;">
                       <tr>
                            <td width="106" height="65"><a href=" href="http://www.google.co.uk" style="padding: 30px 10px; color:#b9850d; text-decoration: none !important;">Delighted</a></td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>                    
                </a>
            </td>            
        </tr>       
    </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tbscgbvy/

As you can see it works in a browser but I can't get it to work when I use it as an email template so that it shows in Outlook.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of padding give height and  width:130px; height:130px;

Comment: this is the way to wirte anchor tag inline css
<a style=" text-decoration: none !important;  width: 130px; background: #cd3333; color: #cd3333; display: block;height: 130px;" class="red"  href="http://www.google.co.uk">

Answer (score 0):

I think this happened because of your code have syntax error in every `a` tag. Please resolved it.

`<a href=" href="http://www.google.co.uk" style="padding: 30px 10px; color:#66CC33; text-decoration: none !important;">Happy</a>`

must be like that:

`<a href="http://www.google.co.uk" style="padding: 30px 10px; color:#66CC33; text-decoration: none !important;">Happy</a>`

Comment: Hi, this was just me being an idiot when I replaced the urls in the snippet. I don't have that in my actual code. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer above states, there is an error in your Hyperlinks. I edited the snippet.

```html
<div style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; overflow:hidden;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px 5px; margin: 0 0; width: 320px;">
        <tr>
            <td width="25%" style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center;">
                <a style=" text-decoration: none !important; padding: 30px 10px; width: 106px; background: #cd3333; color: #cd3333; display: block;" class="red" width="106px" height="65px" href="http://www.google.co.uk">                    
                   <table style="background: #cd3333; color: #cd3333;">
                       <tr>
                            <td width="106" height="65"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" style="padding: 30px 10px; color:#CC3333; text-decoration: none !important;">Unhappy</a></td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>                    
                </a>
            </td>
            
            <td width="25%" style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center;">
                <a style=" text-decoration: none !important; padding: 30px 10px; width: 106px; background: #ffb50e; color: #ffb50e; display: block;" href=" href="http://www.google.co.uk" class="amber" width="106px" height="65px">                    
                    <table style="background: #ffb50e; color: #ffb50e;">
                       <tr>
                            <td width="106" height="65"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" style="padding: 30px 10px; color:#FFB40D; text-decoration: none !important;">Acceptable</a></td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>                    
                </a>
            </td>
            
            <td width="25%" style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center;">
                <a style=" text-decoration: none !important; padding: 30px 10px; width: 106px; background: #67cb33; color: #67cb33; display: block;"  class="green" width="106px" height="65px" href=" href="http://www.google.co.uk">                    
                    <table style="background: #67cb33; color: #67cb33;">
                       <tr>
                            <td width="106" height="65"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" style="padding: 30px 10px; color:#66CC33; text-decoration: none !important;">Happy</a></td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>                    
                </a>
            </td>
    
            <td width="25%" style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center;">
                <a style=" text-decoration: none !important; padding: 30px 10px; width: 106px; background: #b9850d; color: #b9850d; display: block;"  class="gold" width="106px" height="65px" href=" href="http://www.google.co.uk">                    
                    <table style="background: #b9850d; color: #b9850d;">
                       <tr>
                            <td width="106" height="65"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" style="padding: 30px 10px; color:#b9850d; text-decoration: none !important;">Delighted</a></td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>                    
                </a>
            </td>            
        </tr>       
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this was just me being an idiot when I replaced the urls in the snippet. I don't have that in my actual code. Sorry.

Comment: Ah that's fine, I'm glad you found the solution you were looking for, unfortunately I haven't been able to help you out which I am sorry for. Everyone starts at a certain point in programming. We all make mistakes and we all grow, good luck in future projects!